# Cannot read property 'dataArray' of null" in TypeError: Cannot read property 'dataArray' of null

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, expo

This is my code

```
componentDidMount() {
 firebase.database().ref('userlog/').on('value', snapshot => {
  console.log(snapshot.val());
  this.setState({
    dataArray: snapshot.val()
  })
 })
}
```

When I'm trying to check dataArray, console.log(this.state.dataArray);

[ERROR LOG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCKxk.png)

this is my snack link https://snack.expo.io/@syahidahsya/1cec88

Comment: Which line of code is that error referring to?

Comment: Did you declear dataArray in state?
  state = {
    dataArray:[]
  }

Comment: console.log(this.state.dataArray); This line

Comment: I’ve declare dataArray with setState.

Comment: Try declaring it beforehand as an empty array.